# Как сделать фон адаптивным?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Здраствуйте! Суть проблемы: при верстке сайта нужно, чтобы фон корректно отображался на всех устройствах, но при адаптивной верстке у меня фоновое изображение имеющее размеры 1920х1080 получается слишком маленьким для телефона и выглядит это вот так:

[image: Фоновое изображение не адаптируется под устройство]

Вот код:

```
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <form class="box">
            <h1>LOGIN</h1>
            <p>Write your email below and we will send you an email with further instructions.</p>
            <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
            <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail">
            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
            <div class="submit__btn">
                <input id="login" type="submit" value="Log In">
                <input id="signUp" type="button" value="Sign Up" onclick="showEmail()">
                <input id="recover" type="button" value="Recover">
                <input id="back" type="button" value="Back to Login" onclick="showForgotPassForm()">
            </div>
```

```
body {
    background-image: url(img/image.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Пробовал через медиа запросы вставлять другую картинку с размерами 375х812 - результат тот же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ нашёл самостоятельно, просто добавил `min-height: 100vh;` и фон стал адаптивным